# Using jQuery draggable API to scroll sideways or drag down

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, drag

The image below illustrates a problem that I'm experiencing with jQuery's Draggable method. I have a list of products. When users swipe left or right, the products should scroll accordingly. When users swipe down, they should be able to drag the items downward. **Here's the issue: although I can successfully differentiate between vertical and horizontal swipes, I can't enable and disable jQuery drag functionality at the right times.**

[image]

Here is my code:

```
            var touchPos = {
                x: null, 
                y: null,
                threshold: {
                    x: 20, 
                    y: 20
                }
            };

            // Shortcut for getting finger position from touch event
            // This is working correctly 
            var getClient = function (ev, axis) {
                var touches = ev.touches || ev.originalEvent.touches; 
                return touches[0]['client' + axis];
            };

            // All of the products are draggable by default 
            $el.draggable({
                containment: '.pageWrapper',
                cursor: 'move',
                revert: 'invalid',
                helper: 'clone',
                disabled: false 
            });

            function disableDragging () {
                $el.draggable('option', 'cancel', '.planSquare'); 
                $el.draggable("option", "disabled", true );
            }

            function enableDragging () {
                $el.draggable('option', 'cancel', '.pageWrapper'); 
                $el.draggable("option", "disabled", false);
            }

            // When the user starts moving a product
            element.bind('touchstart', function (event) {
                // Capture finger position 
                touchPos.x = getClient(event, 'X'); 
                touchPos.y = getClient(event, 'Y'); 

                if ($el.hasClass('unselectable')) {
                    return false; 
                }

                $el.css('border-color', 'transparent');
            });

            element.bind('touchmove', function(event) { 
                // Update the position of the user's finger
                var newY = getClient(event, 'Y'); 
                var newX = getClient(event, 'X'); 

                var draggingDown = newY - touchPos.y >= touchPos.threshold.y; 
                var draggingSideways = Math.abs(newX - touchPos.x) >= touchPos.threshold.x; 

                if (!draggingDown && draggingSideways) {
                    disableDragging(); 
                }
            });

            // When the user stops moving a square
            element.bind('touchend', function () {
                touchPos.x = null; 
                touchPos.y = null;
                enableDragging(); 

                $el.css('border-color', '#ccc')
            });
```

The `enableDragging` and `disableDragging` have the desired effect when I call them outside the context of the touch event. My hypothesis is that, using jQuery UI, I can't disable dragging once a drag event has already begun. To recap, my goal is to disable dragging and switch to native horizontal scrolling if the user is not dragging down.

Can someone recommend a good approach for toggling between dragging and native scrolling behavior?